# Add UI elements at the end of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add various things below a UITableView (group styled). Like images and buttons. So that they arrange themselves just below the table. (The table's height is variable).

How would I do this? Normally I guess you would just put them in the last cells of the table, but this doesn't seem possible with the grouped view, since it draws those round boxes that I don't want around the buttons and images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `tableFooterView` to whatever you want to appear at the bottom.

Comment: was just typing the same thing... :-) Voted up!